# Acumatica REST API - filter by a stock item attribute

Tags: acumatica

I am looking to get a list of **StockItems** based on the value of one of its attributes via the REST API.

Is this possible and if so how is it done?

Something similar to the below (where ITEMWEB6 is the attribute id).

acumatica.com/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem?$select=*,attributes,UOMConversions,Categories,WarehouseDetails&$expand=attributes,UOMConversions,Categories,WarehouseDetails&**$filter=ITEMWEB6_Attributes eq '1'**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to filter the

acumatica.com/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem?$expand=attributes,UOMConversions,Categories,WarehouseDetails&$filter=AttributeID eq 'ITEMWEB6'

This is not supported since Attribute ID is part of details section and not the Top-Level entity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1JTp.png)

Link: https://help-2021r2.acumatica.com/(W(5))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=f279ec05-2f71-4376-a76f-d3ed0e0e2556